# Using pixel_labels, how to separate objects in an image by color, which will result in three images in python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I am using Kmeans algorithm for creating clusters in an image but I wanted to display seperate clusters of an image. Example if value of K=3 for an image then I wanted to save each seperated cluster portion in a different file. I want to implement this code using python.

I have applied KMeans clustering algorithm clusters are showing but in the same plot.

Comment: Try modifying your plotting code!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with paddington on the left, and assume you have k-means clustered him down to 3 colours on the right/second image:

[image]  [image]

Now we find the unique colours, and iterate over them. Inside the loop, we use `np.where()` to set all pixels of the current colour to white and all others to black:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load kmeans output image
im = cv2.imread('kmeans.png')

# Get list of unique colours
uniquecols = np.unique(im.reshape(-1,3), axis=0) 

# Iterate over unique colours
for i, c in enumerate(uniquecols):
    filename = f"colour-{i}.png"
    print(f"Processing colour {c} into file {filename}")

    # Make output image white wherever it matches this colour, and black elsewhere
    result = np.where(np.all(im==c,axis=2)[...,None], 255, 0)
    cv2.imwrite(filename, result)
```

**Sample Output**

```
Processing colour [48 38 35] into file colour-0.png
Processing colour [138 140 152] into file colour-1.png
Processing colour [208 154  90] into file colour-2.png
```

And the three images are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Change the `np.where()` line as follows if you prefer the alternative output:

```
# Make output image white wherever it doesn't match this colour
result = np.where(np.all(im==c,axis=2)[...,None], c, 255)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Keywords**: Image, image processing, k-means clustering, colour reduction, color reduction, Python, OpenCV, color separation, unique colours, unique colors.