# Segmenting Image by Pixel Value

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-segmentation

I have a large image (about 12000 pixels by 10000) that I am trying to segment by pixel value. The different pixel values for every image were generated with OpenCV's cv.connectedComponentsWithStats. Every single object in the image has a different pixel value and there are about 10k objects in each image. How do I create binary arrays for each object based on different pixel values? Here's an example:

I start with this image:
[image]

Where every green colored object has a different pixel value. How do I make something like this for every single object ?
[image]

Ideally, this would take one input array with n different pixel values for each object and return n binary arrays for each object.

Comment: That could use a lot of memory... what do you plan to do with all those masks? Can you maybe generate them one-at-a-time dynamically as you need them?

Comment: I am labelling buildings and vegetation in elevation maps. In each image there are thousands of buildings and tree and I need to do analysis on each one separately.

Comment: Even if it's a binary image, the best OpenCV/Numpy will do is 8 bits per pixel. That's 1.2E12 bytes.... so I wouldn't keep them all in memory at the same time. To make a mask for one particular label, something like `cv2.inRange` or some numpy equivalent (search around, there are many examples) would do.

Comment: Actually, that's the same as this question... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58670508/2836621