# What can be a faster way to iterate through the pixels of an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, pixel

I'm trying to loop through all the pixels of an image using Pillow then append the pixels with their corresponding RGBA color into a dictionary

What I have at present is:

```py
pixels = {}
frame = frame.convert('RGBA')
w = frame.size[0]
h = frame.size[1]
pix = frame.load()
for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        point = str(x) + "," + str(y)
        if not point in pixels:
            pixels[point] = (pix[x,y][0], pix[x,y][1], pix[x,y][2], pix[x,y][3])
```

where `frame` is the Pillow `Image` object

However I couldn't achieve the fastest outcome out of this (the above code takes ~ 0.55 to 1.0 sec for a 800x600 image)

I tried making use of a Pandas DataFrame instead of the `for` loop but it turned out to be much worse (took 13 secs for the same image)

What can be a faster way to achieve the same goal?

**EDIT:** I'm trying to make a screen sharing application with low bandwidth usage by sending only the updated pixels to the user. The above code runs in an infinite loop and compares the `pixels` dict with the previous dict every time then sends only the dict of the updated pixels.

**What's the purpose of the loop?** The loop was put so I can get the x and y points of every RGBA value. Cause if I use something like `list(frame.getdata())` for example I'll get only a list of the RGBA values but I don't know how to access the coordinates of each

Comment: Actually, image processing should be done using some compiled library such as opencv.

Comment: or use `numba`... but what you're doing here is insane. why do you have to put *string keys* into a dictionary when you have numbers? why all of this? it is inexplicable. just keep the array. I can't think of any *good reason* to use a dictionary to hold every pixel. if you can, please explain.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense IMHO, and it is a massive waste of memory and CPU cycles. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I want to access the coordinates of each pixel later, would that be possible with only the indexes of a list?

Comment: Sending a list of coordinates and new values for changed pixels is not all that efficient, unless there are very few scattered pixels that change (depends on your application, but most common scenario is that changes happen in groups of pixels). Instead, do like X does: update all pixels in a rectangular box. Find the bounding box of the changed pixels, crop your image to that box, and send that image together with its top-left position.

Comment: "access the coordinates later", specifically what are you going to do there? generally, yes, everything is possible, but what you're doing here... I lack the words to express how wrong that is

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get a slightly faster version using list comprehension:

```py
pixels = {f"{x},{y}": (*pix[x,y],) for y in range(h) for x in range(w)}
```

It also looks like f-strings are faster than `str(x) + "," + str(y)`.

By the way why do you need the `if` condition in your loop? If I'm not wrong, you should never get the same pair (x,y). Removing the condition should slightly reduce the execution time in your version.

Here are the performances I got on a big image (~4000x1300):

```
Your version:          8.60s (157.61it/s)
Your version (no if): 8.06s (168.25it/s)
List comprehension:   4.29s (315.67it/s)
```

**However**, I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. There is probably a much more efficient way to do it if you tell us a bit more information about your real objective.

Comment: Thank you that's actually much faster. I have updated the question btw

Answer (score 2):

You haven't heard of **`numpy`**.

**Do not use .getdata()!** Use `np.asarray()` instead.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pil_image = Image.open("some_image.jpg")

data = np.asarray(pil_image)

print(data.shape) # (height, width, channels)

x = 123
y = 456
print(data[y, x]) # the three color values at that position

# all red values (red ist the first channel, 0):
red = data[:, :, 0]

# mask of changed pixels, assuming color
mask = (img1 != img2).any(axis=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I still don't understand what you are trying to do, but a vectorised way of getting a list of where specific colours occur in an image is with `np.where()` like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Get repeatable randomness
np.random.seed(42)

# Generate an image 100x100 pixels in range 0..255
im = np.random.randint(0,256,(100,100), np.uint8)

# Find Y and X values where the image is 128
Y, X = np.where(im==128)
```

Check how many we found - we expect 1/256 of the 100x100 pixels to be 128, i.e. around 39:

```
print(len(X), len(Y))
35 35
```

There are some more sophisticated examples of similar things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58670508/2836621).

Comment: the question is worded confusingly, I understand the struggle... but I don't see where anyone requested *selecting colors*

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I took the following sentence as meaning OP wants to know where each/some specific colour occurs... *"The loop was put so I can get the x and y points of every RGBA value"*. I may be hopelessly wrong‍♂️