# I want to create lists when the rgb value is the same a list is created and the pixel coordinates are stored inside for the same rgb value

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel

What I am trying to achieve is that whenever I get the same rgb value the pixel coordinates are stored in a list for every different rgb value

Code:

```py
from PIL import Image,ImageOps
file_name = "test.png"
og_image = Image.open(file_name)
gray_image = ImageOps.grayscale(og_image)
gray_scalefile = f"{file_name[:-3]}gray.png"
gray_image.save(gray_scalefile)
img = Image.open(gray_scalefile).convert('RGB')
pixels = img.load()
width, height = img.size
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r,g,b = pixels[x,y]
        print(x, y, f'{r},{g},{b}')
```

This code uses PIL to convert test.png to a grayscale image and then it gets all the pixels and their rgb values I want to take all the pixel coordinates that are in the same rgb value and store them together for each rgb value that comes so an example is like 80,40 255 0 0
and 70, 20 255 0 0 i want these to go in a list together because they have the same rgb value

Comment: Please update your question with the code you tried to put the data in a list.

Comment: The data is the pixel coordinates and i wanted to store them in different lists whether they have the same rgb value or not

Comment: So what have you tried? Have you ever put data in a list?

Comment: Do you mean you want a list of the coordinates of all the red pixels, another list of the coordinates of the yellow ones and so on? If so, please say what you plan to do with the list because there are better ways of doing this. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want to do. I plan on just using the lists to retrieve certain coordinates easier

Comment: As an alternative to @quamrana excellent answer, you could convert your `PIL Image` to a Numpy array with `na = np.array(PILImage)` and use Numpy functions as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58670508/2836621 Note that `np.where()` gives you the x,y coordinates of all pixels where a condition is true - which seems to be what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just collect all the coordinates by their `r,g,b` values as keys:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

pixels_by_colour = defaultdict(list)
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r,g,b = pixels[x,y]
        pixels_by_colour[(r,g,b)].append((x,y))
```

Now if you think that you want all the coordinates of colour `(r,g,b)` (and there are some):

```py
coords = pixels_by_colour[(r,g,b)]
print(coords)
```